# Prevent CSS Horizontal Drop-Down Menu from "Wrapping"

Tags: html, css

I am getting frustrated at the fact, that this little nice menu will wrap once the browser window is re-sized. How can the wrapping be prevented and it would stay in a fixed state, regardless if the window is resized?

```css
#menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu li a {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #A9BBD3;
  color: #FFF;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #446087;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul ul li a {
  width: 115px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu>ul>li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#nogo">File</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Save</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Save & Exit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Exit</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Edit</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Add</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Delete</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Clear Form</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Reports</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Export to Excel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Export to HTML</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
#menu > ul { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
```

`float: none` is needed to override the rule `#menu li { float: left; }`, which causes the parent `ul`'s `white-space: nowrap` rule to be ignored.

`display: inline-block` produces an inline layout for the list items, but still allows them to be treated like block elements with respect to sizing and positioning.

The negative `margin-right` is needed to override the default conversion of a linebreak in the HTML source to a single space; without it, your top-level menu items will have spaces between them.

`display: inline-block` doesn't work properly in IE7.  A fix is described [here](http://flipc.blogspot.ca/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html):

> to get inline-block working for any element in Internet Explorer simply add "zoom:1; *display: inline; _height: 30px;" to the end of that elements style oh and yes change the height to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

just try `li { display:table-cell; }` instead of `float:left`

Comment: in this case ... maybe this works
`#menu ul { width: 9999px }`
`#menu { overflow:hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

You've set `width: 100%;` on `<div id="menu">`, which means that it'll be 100% as wide as its parent - which boils down to the browser window.

Instead, enforce a minium width roughly equal to the size of the elements contents, `width: 35em;` in this case.  A relative measurement, based on the size of the text, will scale with bigger text, but you'll need to increase it if the contents are bigger.